# AngularJS: How to highlight active nav item directly when pressing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an iPad app made by angular js. Have added highlight functionality to the nav menu. But I'm not completely satisfied with it. The user experience isn't the best.

When pressing a menu item, it doesn't highlight instantly. It doesn't take long time, but the best would be to make it highlight instantly when pressing the finger on the item. How do I do to make it do that?

Here is the code I have:

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="ui-navbar">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#!/" ng-class="getClass('/')" class="ui-state-persist ui-btn"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#!/about" ng-class="getClass('/about')" class="ui-state-persist ui-btn"><span>About</span></a></li>
        </ul>

    </div><!-- /navbar -->

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
myApp.config(["$routeProvider", '$translateProvider', '$translatePartialLoaderProvider', function($routeProvider, $translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider)
{
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "home.html"
    })
    .when("/about", {
        templateUrl : "about.html"
    });

    $translateProvider.useLoaderCache(true);

    $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('locale');
    $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('header');
    $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('footer');

    $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
      urlTemplate: 'lang/{part}-{lang}.json'
    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('sv');

}]);

myApp.controller('HeaderCtrl', function ($scope, $translatePartialLoader, $location, $translate) {

  $translatePartialLoader.addPart('header');

  $scope.getClass = function (path)
  { 
      if ($location.path().substr(0, path.length) == path)
      { 
          if (path == "/" && $location.path() == "/")
          {
            return "ui-btn-active";
          } 
          else if (path == "/")
          {
            return "";
          } 

        return "ui-btn-active"
      } 
      else
      {
        return ""
      } 
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set CSS when ever link is clicked instead of waiting for route to change. Consider following.

```
<body>
  <span ng-controller="NaviCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="item in navi.items">
      <li>
        <a ng-href="#{{ item.link }}"
           ng-class="{ active: item.active }"
           ng-bind="item.name"
           ng-click="navi.setActive(item)">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </span>
</body>
```

---

```
angular
.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
.value('navi', {
  items: [{
    name: 'Home',
    link: '/',
    active: true
  },{
    name: 'About',
    link: '/about',
    active: false  
  }],
  setActive: function(item) {
    angular.forEach(this.items, function(current) {
      current.active = angular.equals(current, item);
    });
  }
})
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        template : '<div>Home</div>'
    })
    .when('/about', {
        template : '<div>About</div>'
    });
})
.controller('NaviCtrl', function($scope, navi) {
  $scope.navi = navi;
});
```

---

```
ul > li .active {
  background-color: #00dd00;
}
```

---

[image: imgur]

Comment: Have found out that it's impossible to get the absolute instant highlight. Not even with tabs `<a ng-click="setActiveTab(1)">Tab1</a>` and `<div ng-if="activeTab == 1">Tab1</div>` its working. There seems to be a small delay with angular js however you do. I'm staring to looking at Mobile Angular UI now instead. http://mobileangularui.com/docs/#sharedstate-service-and-ui-directives